# How to improve an array functions speed in excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, xls

I have a complex array function that takes way too much time to calculate, which is why I'm looking for ways to make it more efficient. Basically, I have a transaction sheet in which I list all goods sold in a bunch of different stores. The formula that I've written picks the **last** stock amount in the list where a **specific good** was sold at a **specific store**. An index match doesn't work here as I have 2 different row arguments. The formula looks as follows:

```
{=INDEX($O$20:O57,MAX(IF($K$20:K57=K58,IF($D$20:D57=D58,ROW($O$20:O57)-MIN(ROW($O$20:O57))+1))),1)}
```

To better explain:
In column O is the amount of stock after each transaction listed (of which I need the last entry in the list)
In column K is the item code for the specific good
In column D is the name of the branch where the good was sold

With increasing transactions, the sheet grows quite substantially and becomes already with ~1,000 rows a time-consuming nightmare. I have written a vba code that copies the entire table except for the last few rows and pastes everything as values back into the table to avoid having too many array formulas in the table, but I can still watch the extended Lord of the Ring cuts while it's computing.

I appreciate any ideas, I'm sure there are ways to make this thing a little faster ;)

Comment: Do the whole thing with vba and do not use formulas in the vba, but work with variant arrays.

Comment: If this formula works, should it be on [codereview.se] instead?  However - have you considered trying to replace the `MAX` with [`MAXIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883), and turn it into a non-Array formula

Comment: Hi Chronocidal, you're saying that my post is in the wrong forum? I've found a bunch of similar questions here and thus thought it could be solved here. @Scott Craner I'm pretty fresh to VBA and don't know too much about variant arrays. It would be helpful if you explain in more detail how that could look like...

Comment: @Matze [so] is typically for "my code does not work, HELP!", while [codereview.se] is for "my code works, but it needs to be better, HELP!".  Essentially, you may have been too successful for this question to be here

Comment: @Chronocidal MAXIFS will not work here as the output is not a number but a row() and as such the return is not possible.

Comment: In VBA, Load all the data into a variant array.  Loop the items in that array from the bottom up and return the first hit where every thing is true to another variant array.  then load the output range with the data from the output array.

Comment: I understand the logic behind what you're saying @Scott Craner, but I'm too much of a VBA idiot to know how to code that and I would thus prefer a solution where I don't have to sit for a day to understand how to do that

Comment: It can't be done with formula any quicker.  Array formulas are great and I use them extensively, but they have their limits.  The only way to speed this up would be to limit the referenced range, so instead of anchoring the top on row 20, choose the minimum size that would guarantee a hit and let the top row move with the formula, but if you cannot make the referenced range smaller then you get what you get with array formulas.

Comment: A minor query:  isn't `MIN(ROW($O$20:O57))` just `20`?  Unless, I suppose, you sometimes have the formula in-or-above row 19?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah, I hadn't taken the time to break the formula down completely at that point.  However, an "Entry ID" column that contained the Row would make that possible - although, it's only twice as fast over 10000 rows.

Comment: @Chronocidal that doesn't sound enough in terms of efficiency. The sheet is already with just 500 rows a nightmare. Before it even hits 10k rows I'd probably smash the screen... Seems like I have no choice but dig into the vba variant array stuff that Scott Craner suggested